# Error Installing/Launching Django Using Pip

Tags: python, django, installation

I have downloaded and pip installed Django, but I can't find an icon or the right link to launch the Django app.

When I search installed files using "Django" I get a zip file,

This is the error I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Plus when I attempt to unzip the Django file, WinRar asks me to purchase a license.

So how do I launch the installed Python environment?

I use WIN10, Python 3.6.2

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no link or icon to launch the Django app unless you have the project open in an IDE like PyCharm or the like with the correct Python PATH, otherwise, you must run it from command-line.

I suggest you open up your terminal and enter `pip --version`, which should return your `pip` version (not an error). Then `pip install Django` just to make sure you have Django installed. Finally, navigate to your project in your terminal and run it with `python manage.py runserver`